# Trouble understanding proof: prime subfield is isomorphic to either $\mathbb {Q}$ or $\mathbb{Z}_p$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

The prime subfield of a field $K$ is isomorphic to either $\mathbb {Q}$ or $\mathbb{Z}_p$. My professor's *very minute* proof goes as follows:

- Let $f : (\mathbb Z, +) \to  (K, +)$ a group homomorphism such that $f(1) = 1_K$. It's simple to verify that $f(ab) = f(a)f(b)$
- The kernel of $f$ can be either $\{0\}$ or not $\{0\}$.
- If it's not zero, then it's exactly $p\mathbb Z$ for some $p$, therefore $Im(f) \cong \mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$
- If it's zero, $f$ is injective, therefore we can define $\phi : \mathbb Q \to K$ such that $\phi(a/b) = f(a)/f(b)$, which is an homomorphism, therefore $\phi(\mathbb Q)$
  is a subfield of $K$ that is isomorphic to $\mathbb Q$.

### What I did & did not understand:

- I did easily verify the first point
- $f$ is a ring homomorphism (not a field homomorphism), so it can be both injective and not injective, so the second point is ok
- I did prove that if the kernel is not $\{0\}$ then there exists a prime such that $\ker f = p\mathbb Z$. One of the things I need clarification with is the $Im(f) \cong Z_p$ step. I understand this is using the homomorphism theorem to show $Im(f) \cong \mathbb Z/\ker f$. Why can the professor use it? It $f$ surjective?
- Finally, I did not understand the last point.

"Beyond finally", and probably most importantly: **What does this have to do with prime subfields?** I can't really see the connection right now..

I've looked through other related questions, yet they did not solve my specific issue, only suggest different proofs.

Comment: What is your definition of "prime subfield"? If it is the smallest field contained in $K$, then this proof shows it must always be one of $\mathbb{Q}$ or $\mathbb{Z}_p$ as 1. Every $K$ contains one of them. 2. None of these contain any smaller fields inside of them.

Comment: "- Finally, I did not understand the last point." Why not? What is the problem? See [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1942821/prime-subfield-is-either-isomorphic-to-mathbbq-or-f-p), or others for help.

Comment: It may help to realize (if you don't already) that the first bullet is a formal way to describe "start with $1$ and keep adding $1$. Either you reach $0$ and loop or you go on forever."

Comment: It might also help to notice that once you've got a $\mathbb{Q}$ in there, you can never have a $\mathbb{Z}_p$.

Comment: @podiki Ah right, number 2 is very helpful. The definition of prime subfield I have is "the intersection of all subfields", and obviously that's the "smallest" subfield. I did not think of $\mathbb Q$ and $\mathbb Z_p$ not having any non-trivial subfields.

Comment: @EthanBolker Yes, I kind of saw that while proving $f(ab) = f(a)f(b)$... so the homomorphism is surjective, as every $k \in K$ can be expressed as a sum of $n$ $1_K$s, for some $n$, which is equal to $f(\sum_{i = 0}^n 1)$, right?

Comment: The homomorphism is surjective onto its image, but not onto $K$. The image is the prime subfield.

Comment: @EthanBolker ah, right, of course it is, in fact that's what the professor used the homomorphism theorem with, makes sense

Comment: Now you can answer your own question and accept the answer so the question does not linger on the unanswered queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the people in the comments, who made me realize the following:

- The second point is quite straight-forward: $f$ is (by definition) surjective onto its image, so the homomorphism theorem can be applied.
- $f$ being injective allows $\phi$ to be a field homomorphism, and since, as before, $\phi$ is surjective onto its image, as well as being injective (because it is a field homomorphism), $\phi(\mathbb Q)$ and $\mathbb Q$ are isomorphic
- What this has to do with prime subfields is simple: $\mathbb Z_p$ and $\mathbb Q$ are prime fields (i.e. have no non-trivial subfields), therefore if there exists a subfield of $K$ isomorphic to one of these, it has to be the "smallest" subfield of $K$ (the prime subfield).