# understanding over the proof of a theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

> Let $K$ be a field and let $P\subset K$ its prime field (or minimal field).Then:

1. $char  K=p>0 \iff P\simeq\Bbb F_p$ where p is a prime number
2. $char K=0 \iff P\simeq\Bbb Q$

Therefore , barring isomorphisms, the only prime fields are $\Bbb Q$ and the fields $\Bbb F_p$

For the proof we consider the canonical homomorphism of rings $\varphi:\Bbb Z\rightarrow K$:it factors through the prime field $P\subset K$ thus hold $im \varphi\subset P$
.

The reverse implication is trivial($P\subset im\varphi$); but my question is why we can assert that $im\varphi \subset \Bbb P$ ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trouble understanding proof: prime subfield is isomorphic to either $\mathbb {Q}$ or $\mathbb{Z}_p$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4691758/trouble-understanding-proof-prime-subfield-is-isomorphic-to-either-mathbb-q) BTW, the reverse implication need not hold.

Comment: but $im\varphi $ Is a subfield of the field $ K$ so it contains the prime field $P$

Comment: It doesn't if we're talking about $\Bbb Q$ :-)

Comment: you mean that before we have to make explicit $char K$ ?